# I keep getting this IndentationError: unexpected indent error

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, indentation

File "E:\P-L\Atom\RPS.py\RPS.py", line 34
if user_choice == "r":
IndentationError: unexpected indent

i'm new to code and i'm making a project
someone said the you learn better by doing projects
so here i am

i'm getting this on Atom
i've tried the same code on repl.it and it works

```
import random

comp_wins = 0
player_wins = 0

def Choose_Option():
    user_choice = input("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
    if user_choice in ["Rock", "rock", "r", "R"]:
        user_choice = "r"
    elif user_choice in ["Paper", "paper", "p", "P"]:
        user_choice = "p"
    elif user_choice in ["Scissors", "scissors", "s", "S"]:
        user_choice = "s"
    else:
        print("I don't understand, try again.")
        Choose_Option()
    return user_choice

def Computer_Option():
    comp_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
    if comp_choice == 1:
        comp_choice = "r"
    elif comp_choice == 2:
        comp_choice = "p"
    else:
        comp_choice = "s"
    return comp_choice


while True:
    print("")
    
    user_choice = Choose_Option()
    comp_choice = Computer_Option()

    print("")
    if user_choice == "r":
         
        if comp_choice == "r":
            print("You chose rock. The computer chose rock. You tied.")
        
        elif comp_choice == "p":
            print("You chose rock. The computer chose paper. You lose.")
            comp_wins += 1
            
        elif comp_choice == "s":
            print("You chose rock. The computer chose scissors. You win.")
            player_wins += 1

    elif user_choice == "p":
        if comp_choice == "r":
            print("You chose paper. The computer chose rock. You win.")
            player_wins += 1
        
        elif comp_choice == "p":
            print("You chose paper. The computer chose paper. You tied.")
            
            
        elif comp_choice == "s":
            print("You chose paper. The computer chose scissors. You lose.")
            comp_wins += 1

    elif user_choice == "s":
        if comp_choice == "r":
            print("You chose scissors. The computer chose rock. You lose.")
            comp_wins += 1
        
        elif comp_choice == "p":
            print("You chose scissors. The computer chose paper. You win.")
            player_wins += 1
            
        elif comp_choice == "s":
            print("You chose scissors. The computer chose scissors. You tied.")

    print("")
    print("Player wins: " + str(player_wins))
    print("Computer wins: " + str(comp_wins))
    print("")
    
    user_choice = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)")
    if user_choice in ["Y", "y", "yes", "Yes"]:
        pass
    elif user_choice in ["N", "n", "no", "No"]:
        break
    else:
        break
```

Pretty sure the problem is with atom but i don't know what it is would love any help.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. Are you sure that the code you've provided is the exact same as the one causing the error? For example, the error you've provided says that it happens on row 34 by this line: `if user_choice == "r": `. However in the provided code that piece of code happens on row 39.

Comment: @Shane Hussain have you tried dedenting  the whole code and indent it again. You can do so by pressing "shift + tab" to dedent the region and press "tab" to indent it again.